# Trusting self signed certificate over https

Tags: android, ssl

I know there are a lot of tutorials on the internet, but they are beyond my scope of knowledge, because it is my first time using https.
I used emmby's answer here [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https/4837230#4837230). But I don't know how the further implementation goes in class where I connect to server.
Here is a code snippet in my HttpsConection class

```
  Log.d("url", url.toString());
        HttpsURLConnection httpsConnection;

        Log.d("HTTP get", "get() called");
        try
        {
            Log.v("HttpConnection", url.toString());
            httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            if (request != null)
            {
                OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
                        httpsConnection.getOutputStream());
                // Log.e(TAG, "created outputstream");

                wr.write(request);
                // Log.e(TAG, "request sent");
                wr.flush();
                wr.close();
            } else
            {
                Log.e("HttpConnection", "Nothing to send to server");
            }

            // Execute
            try
            {

                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(httpsConnection
                        .getInputStream());
                responseString = convertStreamToString(in);
                in.close();
```

I have a *.bks file in my res/raw folder and I am stuck there.

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for self-signed https connection, it works fine for me:

```
        KeyStore trustStore;
        try {
            trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
            trustStore.load(null, null);
            SSLSocketFactory sf = new EasySSLSocketFactory(trustStore);
            sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);
            BasicHttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);
            SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
            registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
            registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));
            ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
            HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(sf.getHostnameVerifier());
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(url);
            BasicHttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 10000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 15000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            httpClient.setParams(httpParameters);
            HttpResponse getResponse = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
            final int statusCode = getResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) 
            { 
                return null;
            }
            HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();
            String content = EntityUtils.toString(getResponseEntity);
            InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            return is;
        } catch (KeyStoreException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (CertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return null;
```

Comment: Doesn't it allow all certificates?

Comment: yes, is set by *sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER)*

Comment: Sorry, but I want to allow only one certificate.

Comment: I know, but the self-signed certificate comes from YOUR server, so if your app make connection only to this one there isn't any problem with allow all hostname.